# Any tips to improve this function? Looking to reduce lines by ~5-10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am taking a python course and was asked to define a function. While I did get the function right, and it works in every test case provided by the course and that I tried myself, I was wondering if and where I could slim down the code(pasted below). The course feed claims that it can be written in 15-20 lines, and mine is at 27. Thanks!

```
def playGame(wordList):
    """
    Allow the user to play an arbitrary number of hands.

    1) Asks the user to input 'n' or 'r' or 'e'.
      * If the user inputs 'n', let the user play a new (random) hand.
      * If the user inputs 'r', let the user play the last hand again.
      * If the user inputs 'e', exit the game.
      * If the user inputs anything else, tell them their input was invalid.

    2) When done playing the hand, repeat from step 1
    """
    draw = input("Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end the game: ")
    while draw != 'n':
        if draw == 'r':
            print("You have not played a hand yet. Please play a new hand first!")
            print('')
            draw = input("Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end the game: ")
        elif draw == 'e':
            break
        else: 
            print("Invalid command.")
            print('')
            draw = input("Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end the game: ")
    while True:
        if draw == 'n':
            hand = dealHand(HAND_SIZE)
            playHand(hand, wordList, HAND_SIZE)
            print('')
            draw = input("Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end the game: ")
        elif draw == 'r':
            playHand(hand, wordList, HAND_SIZE)
            print('')
            draw = input("Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end the game: ")
        elif draw == 'e':
            return
        else:
            print("Invalid command.")
            print('')
            draw = input("Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end the game: ")
```

Comment: A small thing would be to remove `print('')` and use `\n`. For example: `print("Invalid command.\n")`.

Comment: This should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, not here

Comment: Line numbers are an arbitrary metric. With this code going from 27 lines to 15-20 would be at the expense of clarity (though a few lines could be shaved off). Why bother?

Comment: Whenever you reuse a string multiple times, store it as a variable instead of re-typing, it might not save you lines, but it will save characters and make the code easier to maintain

Answer (score 1):

While this is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ like @TomDalton suggests, I do see an opportunity to give an example that hopefully helps you understand control flow in a program like this.  First the updated code:

```
import random

HAND_SIZE = 5

def deal_hand(wordlist, size):
    return random.sample(wordlist, size)

def play_hand(hand):
    print("Words: {}".format(", ".join(hand)))

def play_game(wordlist):
    hand = None
    while True:
        draw = input("Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end the game: ")
        if draw == 'r':
            if not hand:
                print("You have not played a hand yet. Please play a new hand first!")
                continue
            play_hand(hand)
        elif draw == 'n':
            hand = deal_hand(wordlist, HAND_SIZE)
            play_hand(hand)
        elif draw == 'e':
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid command")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    words = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
    play_game(words)
```

Take a minute to read this and see if it makes sense.

The basic idea is we are going to do a single non-terminating loop (`while True`).  After each user input we can decide what to do (`r, n and e`).  You should notice that in your original code the cases for `e` and `unknown` are the exact same.  You also have a loop that continues until `n` is entered.  I think you ended up this way specifically because you wanted to handle the `r` case when it was the first choice entered (when there was no hand to repeat).  But you can check that case inside of a single `if` that will either: tell the user they need to do `n` first, or repeat the last hand if a hand has already been generated.

The key is converting your comment (doc) at the top into code.  This implementation matches the text description much more accurately.